# How can I switch the weather layout in Beautiful Widgets from clock/current conditions mode to forecast mode?

Tags: lock-screens, app-widgets

I am trying to setup a lock-screen widget set to suit my liking.  I have the top of the screen covered exactly how I want it with the current weather, clock, and battery meter provided by SiMi widgets, shown below.

The bar underneath it is Beautiful Widgets Small Weather.  In many screenshots (including the second one shown, below) I see Beautiful Widgets set in forecast mode, where it shows only the forecast for the next few days rather than a clock and current weather.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to cause the widget to go into this mode, and I'm hoping others here might know the answer.

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I'd like the weather line (below my dark conditions/clock/battery) to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beautiful Widgets installs a bunch of individual widgets that can be used. The one with the clock and weather is the "SuperClock" (or "Beautiful Home", maybe) widget. It sounds like you just need to select "Beautiful Weather 4x1" when picking a widget (unless the lock screen widget thingy doesn't give that choice - is that the case?).

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right!  I figured this out myself but a moment ago and came to answer my own question.  You'll get accepted answer as soon as it lets me do so :)  Thanks!